# How does Human Nature relate to Angelic Nature, specifically regarding sin and free-will?

Tags: sin, satan, nature-of-man, angels, fall-of-man

I have seen quite a few questions on here asking: How could Lucifer, being a perfect creation, have fallen or sinned?

However, my question is this:

What can we find in the Scriptures about the nature of Angels? Does it relate at all to the nature of humans, and can a comparison be made between the fall of man and the fall of Lucifer and his angels?

We know that both humans and angels are guilty of sin. But we know that evil existed before humanity fell to sin, as Eve was deceived. However, is there any evidence as to how Lucifer fell?

> 2 Peter 2:4-- 4 For if God did not spare angels when they sinned, but cast them into hell and committed them to pits of darkness, reserved for judgment;
>
> Romans 3:23--23 for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,
>
> 1 Timothy 2:12-14--12 But I do not allow a woman to teach or exercise authority over a man, but to remain quiet. 13 For it was Adam who was first created, and then Eve. 14 And it was not Adam who was deceived, but the woman being deceived, fell into transgression.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paul is quite specific as to how sin entered our own sphere of existence :

> ... **by one man sin entered into the world**, and death by sin; and so death passed upon all men, for that all have sinned: [Romans 5:12, KJV.]

In this particular place he attributes the entrance of sin, into our own realm, to one man. The text you quote in I Timothy enlarges on that and conveys the role played by woman.

The writer to the Hebrews conveys three things about the nature of angels :

> And of the angels he saith, Who maketh his angels spirits, and his ministers a flame of fire. [Hebrews 1:7, KJV.]

Firstly, as to their being, they are spirit-beings, that is to say, they have no personal material or substantive form as we humans do. It is clear from many scriptures that they may, as messengers (which is what both the Hebrew *malak* and the Greek *aggelos* mean) take, temporarily, either a manifestation of humanity or they may appear in a dream in a form which expresses their messenger role.

Secondly, the nature of their life, the way in which their life functions (which will be different from humans whose 'life' is in their 'blood', that is to say breathed in atmosphere flowing through the bloodstream to every part of the body energises human nature). The mode of the life-function of angels is likened (so that we may understand it) to fire - a burning, non-solid, energy.

Thirdly, their existence is (as should also be the case for humans) a continual service towards God, as Gabriel made clear to Zachariah when he said :

> I am Gabriel, that stand in the presence of God; and am sent to speak unto thee, and to shew thee these glad tidings. [Luke 1:19, KJV.]

The writer to the Hebrews also makes clear what the remedy is for sin, with regard to humans :

> And deliver them who through fear of death were all their lifetime subject to bondage. For verily he took not on him the nature of angels; but he took on him the seed of Abraham. [Hebrews 2:15 and 16, KJV.]

Speaking of Jesus Christ, the writer makes it clear that Jesus Christ 'took on' the nature of humanity in order that humans might be redeemed from sin. By partaking of their nature and suffering on their behalf, he redeemed them from the transgression of humanity.

I can find nothing in scripture that expresses anything similar to this in regard to angels except the expression 'elect angels' :

> I charge thee before God, and the Lord Jesus Christ, and **the elect angels**, that thou observe these things ... [I Timothy 5:21, KJV.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You make some great points on the nature of man, as well as, on the nature of the life of angels. I am still wondering though, and maybe this should be a separate question, but, is there any scriptural evidence as to what may have caused Lucifer and the angels to sin against God? How does one who sees God face to face rise up in pride?

Comment: With regard to editing 'energise' is the BrE spelling and 'energize' is the AmE. But I have edited the two typos, as noticed.